Telegram Bot ConversationHandler Skips Waiting for User Input and Gives AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reply_text'
I'm building a Telegram bot that interacts with users to edit and upload videos using the python-telegram-bot library. The bot retrieves videos from Reddit, edits them using moviepy, and then asks the user for additional input through a conversation handler. However, I'm encountering a couple of issues:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reply_text': I receive this error when the bot tries to call reply_text on update.message.reply_text("test")

Conversation Skipping Input: When I use update.effective_message.reply_text (which isnt None) to ask a question, the bot skips waiting for the user's answer and starts re-uploading the next video in the loop.


Here is the relevant code snippet for the start_editor_questions function, which is used in a conversation handler:
async def start_editor_questions(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> int:
    """Starts the conversation by sending the video and asking the first question."""
    output_filename = context.user_data.get('output_filename')
    
    await context.bot.send_video(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, video=open(output_filename, 'rb'))
    await update.effective_message.reply_text("What height do you want? (h1/h2)")
    
    return HEIGHT

Here is my main:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = Application.builder().token('YOUR_TOKEN').build()
    
    # Register handlers
    start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)
    application.add_handler(start_handler)
    application.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button_handler))

    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler("start", start_editor_questions)],
        states={
            HEIGHT: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, height_response)],
            TRIM: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, trim_response)],
            WATERMARK_COLOR: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, watermark_color_response)],
            WATERMARK_OPACITY: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, watermark_opacity_response)],
            TITLE: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, title_response)],
            TITLE_COLOR: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, title_color_response)],
            CAPTION: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, caption_response)],
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler("cancel", cancel)],
    )
    
    application.add_handler(conv_handler)
    application.run_polling(allowed_updates=Update.ALL_TYPES)

I’ve included just the most relevant parts of the code. The complete setup includes additional functions and handlers. For example, here is the function that calls start_editor_questions:
async def process_account_videos(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE, account_name, link, remaining_posts):
    while remaining_posts < 3:
        for video in videos:
            await start_editor_questions(update, context)

Questions:

Why am I getting an AttributeError related to reply_text?
Why is the bot skipping waiting for user input and starting the next video upload immediately?

I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions on how to fix these issues. Please let me know if you need any more code.
EDIT: Added process_account_videos function
async def process_account_videos(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE, account_name, link, remaining_posts):
    print("process_account_videos")
    limit = 1
    after = None
    retrieved_list_file = 'retrieved_list.csv'
   
    file_path = retrieved_list_file
    required_columns = ['time', 'accountname', 'special_name', 'after_retr']
    
    if remaining_posts == 0:
        return
    if not os.path.exists(file_path):
        df = pd.DataFrame(columns=required_columns)
        df.to_csv(file_path, index=False)
        print(f"Created new CSV file: {file_path}")
    else:
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
        missing_columns = [col for col in required_columns if col not in df.columns]
        if missing_columns:
            print(f"Warning: Missing columns {missing_columns}. Recreating the file.")
            df = pd.DataFrame(columns=required_columns)
            df.to_csv(file_path, index=False)
            print(f"Recreated CSV file: {file_path}")

    retrieved_list = pd.read_csv(retrieved_list_file)
    account_data = retrieved_list[retrieved_list['accountname'] == account_name]

    i = 1
    while loop_number < 3:
        account_data = retrieved_list[retrieved_list['accountname'] == account_name]

        check = False
        if not account_data.empty:
            check = True
            account_data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(account_data['time'], errors='coerce')
            account_data = account_data.sort_values(by='time', ascending=False)
            special_name_list = account_data['special_name'].values
            after = account_data.iloc[0]['after_retr']

        url = f"{link}.json?limit={limit}"
        if after:
            url += f"&after={after}"
        print(url)
        response = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "username"})
        
        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = response.json()
            posts = data['data']['children']
            account_folder = f"./downloads/{account_name}"
            os.makedirs(account_folder, exist_ok=True)
            output_folder = f"./downloads/{account_name}/output"
            os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)
            
            for post in posts:
                if check is True:
                    if post['data']['name'] in special_name_list:
                        continue
                if post['data']['secure_media'] is None or post['data']['over_18'] is False:
                    new_row = {
                        'time': pd.Timestamp.now(),
                        'accountname': account_name,
                        'special_name': post['data']['name'],
                        'after_retr': data['data'].get("after")
                    }
                    retrieved_list = pd.concat([retrieved_list, pd.DataFrame([new_row])], ignore_index=True)
                    retrieved_list.to_csv(retrieved_list_file, index=False)
                    continue

                video_url = post['data']['secure_media']['reddit_video']['fallback_url']
                base_video_url = video_url.split("/DASH_")[0]

                audio_url = f"{base_video_url}/DASH_AUDIO_128.mp4"
                audio_response = requests.get(audio_url, stream=True)

                if audio_response.status_code != 200:
                    audio_url = f"{base_video_url}/DASH_audio.mp4"
                    audio_response = requests.get(audio_url, stream=True)

                video_filename = os.path.join(account_folder, f"video{i}.mp4")
                with open(video_filename, "wb") as f:
                    video_response = requests.get(video_url, stream=True)
                    f.write(video_response.content)

                if audio_response.status_code == 200:
                    audio_filename = os.path.join(account_folder, f"audio{i}.mp3")
                    with open(audio_filename, "wb") as f:
                        f.write(audio_response.content)

                    output_filename = os.path.join(output_folder, f"output{i}.mp4")
                    # Using subprocess to merge video and audio
                    subprocess.run(["ffmpeg", "-i", video_filename, "-i", audio_filename, "-c", "copy", output_filename])
                else:
                    output_filename = os.path.join(output_folder, f"output{i}.mp4")
                    os.rename(video_filename, output_filename)
                
                new_row = {
                        'time': pd.Timestamp.now(),
                        'accountname': account_name,
                        'special_name': post['data']['name'],
                        'after_retr': data['data'].get("after")
                    }
                retrieved_list = pd.concat([retrieved_list, pd.DataFrame([new_row])], ignore_index=True)
                retrieved_list.to_csv(retrieved_list_file, index=False)
                
                # Increment the loop_number after each iteration
                loop_number += 1
                i += 1


                context.user_data['account_name'] = account_name
                context.user_data['output_filename'] = output_filename
                await start_editor_questions(update, context)
                
                output_folder = context.user_data.get('output_folder')
                caption_name = context.user_data.get('caption')
                
                await upload(output_folder, caption_name)  # Implement this function according to your needs
               
                if loop_number >= remaining_posts:
                    break
        else:
            print(f"Failed to connect to Reddit. Status code: {response.status_code}")
            break


Answering both of your questions:

"Why am I getting an AttributeError related to reply_text?"
You are allowing all types of updates at application.run_polling(allowed_updates=Update.ALL_TYPES), so do not expect to have the update.message available on every update.



"Why is the bot skipping waiting for user input and starting the next video upload immediately?"
For this one you will have to provide more information on how process_account_videos is being used, because this function seems to be handling every single update: Update (either a message, message reaction, edited message etc.) and repeating the video upload routine - while remaining_posts < 3 - for each of those updates, that is: yes, it would be looping the upload routine in a row if the user send a single message or any other update


Ok I will try to explain it the best I can:
Inside the button_handler:
´await process_account_videos(update, context, account_name, link, remaining_posts´

I added the function "process_account_videos" to the post. So you can see it @luis-cabral

From what I understood, the issue seems to be in the fact you are handling the upload loop inside the process_account_videos handler directly.
Try implementing 3 handlers instead:

A button to trigger a dialog to upload the video
The video upload dialog
The upload routine, containing either a retrigger to the step 2 or a finish message at the end

